# Tensorflow 2.0: how to transform from MapDataset (after reading from TFRecord) to some structure that can be input to model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I've stored my training and validation data on two separate TFRecord files, in which I store 4 values: signal A (float32 shape (150,)), signal B (float32 shape (150,)), label (scalar int64), id (string). My parsing function for reading is:

```py
def _parse_data_function(sample_proto):

    raw_signal_description = {
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }

    for key, item in SIGNALS.items():
        raw_signal_description[key] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature(item, tf.float32)

    # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(sample_proto, raw_signal_description)
```

where `SIGNALS` is a dictionary mapping *signal name*->*signal shape*. Then, I read the raw datasets:

```py
training_raw = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(<path to training>), compression_type='GZIP')
val_raw = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(<path to validation>), compression_type='GZIP')
```

and use map to parse the values:

```py
training_data = training_raw.map(_parse_data_function)
val_data = val_raw.map(_parse_data_function)
```

Displaying the header of `training_data` or `val_data`, I get:

`<MapDataset shapes: {Signal A: (150,), Signal B: (150,), id: (), label: ()}, types: {Signal A: tf.float32, Signal B: tf.float32, id: tf.string, label: tf.int64}>`

which is pretty much as expected. I also checked some of the values for consistency and they seemed to be correct.

Now, to my issue: **how do I get from the MapDataset, with the dictionary like structure, to something that can be given as input to the model?**

The input to my model is the pair (Signal A, label), though in the future I will use Signal B as well.

The simplest way to me seemed to create an generator over the elements that I want. Something like:

```py
def data_generator(mapdataset):
    for sample in mapdataset:
        yield (sample['Signal A'], sample['label'])
```

However, with this approach I lose some convenience of Datasets, such as batching, and it is also not clear how to use the same approach for the `validation_data` paramenter of `model.fit`. Ideally, I would only convert between the map representation and the Dataset representation where it iterates over pairs of Signal A tensors and labels.

EDIT: My end product should be something with a header akin to:
`<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((150,), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>`
But not necessarily `TensorSliceDataset`

Comment: Have you tried dataset.as_numpy_iterator() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do this in the parse function. For example:

```
def _parse_data_function(sample_proto):

    raw_signal_description = {
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }

    for key, item in SIGNALS.items():
        raw_signal_description[key] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature(item, tf.float32)

    # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
    parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(sample_proto, raw_signal_description)

    return parsed['Signal A'], parsed['label']
```

If you `map` this function over the `TFRecordDataset`, you will have a dataset of *tuples* `(signal_a, label)` instead of a dataset of dictionaries. You should be able to put this into `model.fit` directly.